# Apply function to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

So I've got a dataframe. I fetch all the numerical columns that matter and they are stored in `bookies` (which is a list).

I then want to apply the kelly criterion (defined below) on each of these bookies against the model:

```
def kelly_criterion(bookie_odds, model):
    kelly = (((bookie_odds-1) * model ) - (1-model)) / (bookie_odds-1)
    return kelly
```

This is how I'm trying to apply it:

```
for bookie in bookies:
    df[bookie + "_kelly"] = df[bookie].apply(kelly_criterion(df[bookie],df["win"]))
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

All the columns I'm using are of type float64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pd.Series.apply` works with one column only and passes values.

`pd.DataFrame.apply` works with multiple columns and passes `pd.Series` objects.

You can still use `pd.Series.apply` if you redefine your function:

```
def kelly_criterion(model, bookie_odds):
    kelly = (((bookie_odds-1) * model ) - (1-model)) / (bookie_odds-1)
    return kelly

for bookie in bookies:
    df[f'{bookie}_kelly'] = df['win'].apply(kelly_criterion, bookie_odds=bookie)
```

However, you *should* use vectorised methods to leverage the Pandas framework:

```
for bookie in bookies:
    num = (df[bookie] - 1) * df['win'] - 1 + df['win']
    denum = df[bookie] - 1
    df[f'{bookie}_kelly'] = num / denum
```

For complete vectorisation:

```
kellies = [f'{bookie}_kelly' for bookie in bookies]

bookies_sub_1 = df[bookies] - 1
df[kellies] = (bookies_sub_1 * df['win'] - 1 + df['win']) / bookies_sub_1
```

Comment: Great answer +1, For completeness you could show how the calculation can be fully vectorized by removing the for bookie in bookies loop

Answer (score 2):

In this case it doesn't look like you need to use apply as your function takes in and returns a Series of the same shape. Apply can be more suitable when doing operations on individual elements, but it looks like this vectorizes:

```
for bookie in bookies:
    df[bookie + "_kelly"] = kelly_criterion(df[bookie],df["win"])
```